# Bogus - Faker to pick a random custom type

Tags: c#, bogus

Have this:

```
        var SampleNames = new PersianName[] {
            new XName("Sara","Dianov"),
            new XName("Eliza","Raas"),
            new XName("Robert","Smith")
        };

        var theFaker = new Faker<Architect>()
        .RuleFor(h => h.User.NameBundle, f => f.PickRandom(SampleNames))
```

**Get this error:**

```
Error: System.ArgumentException: 
Your expression 'h.User.NameBundle' cant be used. 
Nested accessors like 'o => o.NestedObject.Foo' at a parent level are not allowed.
 You should create a dedicated faker for NestedObject like new Faker<NestedObject>().RuleFor(o => o.Foo, ...)
 with its own rules that define how 'Foo' is generated.
 See this GitHub issue for more info: https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/issues/115
```

How can I resolve the issue? Have read the provided link in the error message, BTW I couldn't resolve it yet.
I wanted to assign a random `XName` element to the `h.User.NameBundle`, don't if I really need the second faker here and not sure how can I use a separate Faker to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another faker for nested types. You could then reference it in the other faker like this `.RuleFor(h => h.User, () => userFaker)`. Here's a sample:

```
var samples = new Name[] 
{
    new Name { FistName = "Sara", LastName = "Dianov" },
    new Name { FistName = "Eliza", LastName = "Raas" },
    new Name { FistName = "Robert", LastName = "Smith" }
};

var userFaker = new Faker<User>()
    .RuleFor(h => h.Name, f => f.PickRandom(samples));

var someClassFaker = new Faker<SomeClassWithPropUser>()
    .RuleFor(h => h.User, () => userFaker);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, It caused me to change some other constructors and other parts of the code, but it may solve the issue, guess will try the new code tomorrow, and will give you the feedback. A problem I may had with a similar approach was that I used the 2nd faker like this: "var nameFaker = new Faker<Name>()", and didn't know how to pass it. Now though your answer may work, with your approach I need to re-manage some parts. Thanks +1

Comment: Now trying to adapt it to my needed scenario, have this question: can I use the child faker in the instructor of the parent faker like this: ".CustomInstantiator(() => userFaker())" ? I know it is wrong and need some minor fixes.